# App Engine: Using f1-micro instance but getting billed for g1-small instance

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

We have a flexible environment (node.js) running with one f1-micro (1 vCPU, 0.6 GB memory) instance. When I look at the Billing History, I can see that we get billed for "Compute Engine Small instance with 1 VCPU" with the price of a g1-small instance.

We're still in the 60 days free trial period, so we are still using the credit.

But I'm wondering why we get billed for the g1-small instance if we are using f1-micro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question: We actually got billed for "Compute Engine Micro instance with burstable CPU" (f1-micro) correctly by the end of month. It seems that there is a delay between what is really consumed and what is shown under "Costs in this month".

app.yaml:

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1

resources:
  cpu: .5
  memory_gb: 0.90
  disk_size_gb: 10

skip_files:
  - ^(.*/)?.*/node_modules/.*$

env_variables:
...
```

Comment: May I please see your configurations file?
I'm having a little difficulty getting an f1-micro to work under the flexible environment.

Comment: Added the configuration above.